# Entity Framework - Many to Many self join reversed

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table (Artist) which has a many to many relationship with itself (An artist can be a band or a person).

My classes are declared below:

```
public class Artist
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ArtistMember> Members { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArtistMember> MemberOf { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistMember
{
    public int BandID { get; set; }
    public int MemberID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

And mapped here:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Artist>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Members)
    .WithRequired(e => e.Member)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.MemberID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Artist>()
    .HasMany(e => e.MemberOf)
    .WithRequired(e => e.Band)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.BandID)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<ArtistMember>().ToTable("ArtistMember", "Music").HasKey(am => new { am.BandID, am.MemberID });
```

The issue is that when I want to insert data into the structure I have to reverse it to get it to work.

```
// Create New Band
TRN.Models.Artist b = new Artist();
b.Name = "Band";

// Create New Member
TRN.Models.Artist m = new Artist();
m.Name = "Member";

// Create Link
ArtistMember am = new ArtistMember();
am.Band = b;
am.Member = m;

b.MemberOf.Add(am);
```

A band is created as a member of a solo artist. It is however stored correctly in the database.

What do I need to do to store the relationship correctly in entity framework?

Comment: Isn't a 1-to-many better to use here, as *one* Band has *many* Members? I would simply register solo artists as a band with one member. If that needs to be visually different in the application, you can always filter the band list between those with a single member, and those with multiple members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the mapping reversed because each modelBuilder statement describes a single relationship. You currently have:

```
Artist.Members  <---- inverse of ----> ArtistMember.Member
Artist.MemberOf <---- inverse of ----> ArtistMember.Band
```

which doesn't make sense because if an `bandArtist` has `Members`, in the `ArtistMember` objects that join `bandArtist` and `Members`, `ArtistMember.Band` should reference `bandArtist`.

---

I think you're looking for:

```
Artist.Members  <---- inverse of ----> ArtistMember.Band
Artist.MemberOf <---- inverse of ----> ArtistMember.Member
```

which means you'll need:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Artist>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Members)
    .WithRequired(e => e.Band)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.BandID);

modelBuilder.Entity<Artist>()
    .HasMany(e => e.MemberOf)
    .WithRequired(e => e.Member)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.MemberID);
```

It might even make more sense to start from the other side of the relationships:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ArtistMember>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Band)
    .WithMany(e => e.Members)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.BandID);

modelBuilder.Entity<ArtistMember>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Member)
    .WithMany(e => e.MemberOf)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.MemberID);
```

So if you're looking for a band's members, you'll do something like:

```
bandArtist.Members.Select(am => am.Member)
```

As an aside, I removed `WillCascadeOnDelete(false)`, because it probably doesn't make sense to leave stray `ArtistMember` rows if the corresponding `Artist` on either side is deleted.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for much for this.

I had to leave WillCascadeOnDelete(false) in as it would not deploy without it but otherwise it works a treat.